# Second leaflet map from a component is not showing up

Tags: angular, leaflet, components

Before you start looking into this, be aware I've only provided info/some code on what the problem is because I can't publish all my code. I'm hoping someone has run into something similar and can provide tips/guidance for me to find the root cause of this issue.

*File structure explanation:* I have a **location-component** that's used in **add-** and **edit-** components. The add and edit parts are modals for the **incidents** and **work-needs** tabs in a main **layout** page.
[image]

The `location-component` shows a map (hidden by default) when I click a button "Pick Location" or hides it with "Close Map". That all works fine, the problem is some weird scenario-based behavior...

If I refresh my browser while on the **work-needs** tab (so the tab shown after refresh is work-needs), neither the **add-** or **edit-** modals will show the map.

However, refreshing the browser on the **incidents** tab works correctly: the map shows and hides as expected.

The really weird part is the following behaviour:

- Refresh on **work-needs** (map doesn't show for these add/edit modals)
- Click on **incidents** tab, which doesn't refresh the page (map is showing for these add/edit modals)
- Click on **work-needs** tab again, which doesn't refresh the page (map is NOW SHOWING for these add/edit modals)

I've been scratching my head about this for a while, any help would be appreciated!

[image]

In HTML, the map is held as usual with leaflet:

```
<div id="map" class="mapEdit" [hidden]="!mapVisible"></div>
```

Here is the location component:

```js
/*obviously there's more code in this component but these are the relevant
functions. The rest is just data unrelated to map passed around and displayed. I'll add more of my code if needed, but the map stuff is isolated
to this location-component*/
 
import { Component, OnChanges, EventEmitter, Output, forwardRef, Input, SimpleChanges, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import * as Leaflet from "leaflet";
import { AppSettings } from '../../../shared/models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-location',
  templateUrl: './location.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => LocationComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class LocationComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {
  public location: any = {};
  public locationMap: string;

  constructor() { }
   
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  
  public mapVisible: boolean = false;
  public updatingMapImage: boolean = false;

  private map: any;
  private marker: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMap(AppSettings.DEFAULT_LOCATION);
  }

  open() { //is called when the modal starts up
    this.resetMap();
    if (this.location.latitude && this.location.longitude) {
        this.setMarker([this.location.latitude, this.location.longitude]);
    }
  }

  // Map //

  showMap() {
    this.mapVisible = true;
  }

  closeMap() {
    this.mapVisible = false;
  }

  loadMap(center) {

    this.map = Leaflet
        .map('map')
        .setView(center, AppSettings.DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM)
        .on("click", this.onMapClicked.bind(this));

    
Leaflet.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(this.map);
}

  resetMap() {
    if (this.map) {
        var location = AppSettings.DEFAULT_LOCATION;
        this.closeMap();
        this.removeMarker();
        this.map.setView(location);
    }
  }

  onMapClicked(event) {
    this.location.latitude = event.latlng.lat;
    this.location.longitude = event.latlng.lng;

    var location = [this.location.latitude, this.location.longitude]
    this.setMarker(location)
  }

  setMarker(location) {
    this.removeMarker();
    this.marker = Leaflet
        .marker(location)
        .addTo(this.map);
    this.map.setView(location);
  }

  removeMarker() {
      if (this.marker) {
          this.map.removeLayer(this.marker);
      }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

  }

  // Interface Implementation
  propagateChange = (_: any) => { };

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.location = value;

    if (this.location) {
      this.open();
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() { }
}
```

Comment: That is nice talk and screenshot about your app, but it does not seem to help understand your issue. If you have access to all your source code, can test your app behaviour live, but could not figure it out, how can you seriously expect anyone else to debug it for you based on 1 screenshot (that does not even show the problem) and 1 page of code with no template?

Comment: @ghybs It would be better if you asked for more info/code instead of just gripe about my lack thereof. I think it's clear I don't expect someone to come debug my code for me or I WOULD have thrown all my code here or in a plunker. And a screenshot with the map NOT showing would not just have been of no use (since you CAN'T SEE IT or where it goes), it would have probably caused some confusion (again, because you can't see it).

My intention was to see if anyone has run into something similar get their guidance into troubleshooting and eventually finding the root cause of this problem.

Comment: The [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) provide some guidance. Furthermore, what you think is a map not showing might still be informative (typically tiles not showing, but controls do). I also see that you have a custom `mapVisible` flag that you never mentioned. Do not expect people to guide you on a long run: if they cannot find a solution in 1 or 2 feedbacks, most will move away from your question.